# Tic-Tac-Toe display not displaying correctly

Tags: java, display, tic-tac-toe

So I have created a simple tic-tac-toe console program. But for some reason my methods aren't displaying the board correctly.

The display of the code prints out like this:

```
Tic-Tac-Toe
------------

Player 'X', enter move (row [1-3] column [1-3]): 2
2

|

|


-----------

|
 X 
|


-----------

|

|



Player 'O', enter move (row [1-3] column [1-3]):
```

The code:

```
/**
 *  The grid represents the game board
 */
public class Grid {

    int ROWS = 3;                                                   // Defines the amount of rows
    int COLUMNS =3;                                                 // Defines the amount of columns

    Box[][] board;                                                  // Represents the game board as a grid
    int currentrow, currentcol;                                     // Row and Column that was played last

    public Grid()
    {
        board = new Box[ROWS][COLUMNS];                             // Constructor initializes the game board
        for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                board[row][col] = new Box(row,col);
            }
        }
    }
    public void init()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {                      // Re-initializes the game board
            for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                board[row][col].clear();
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean isDraw()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {                      // Returns true if the game is a draw (no more empty boxes)
            for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                if (board[row][col].content == Player.EMPTY) {
                    return false;                                   // An empty box found, not a draw, exits
                }
            }
        }
        return true;                                                // No empty boxes return true is then a draw
    }
    public boolean hasWon(Player thePlayer) {
        return (board [currentrow] [0] .content == thePlayer && board [currentrow] [1].content == thePlayer && board [currentrow] [2].content == thePlayer // 3 in a row
                || board [0] [currentcol].content == thePlayer && board [1] [currentcol].content == thePlayer && board [2] [currentcol].content == thePlayer // 3 in a column
                || currentrow == currentcol
                && board[0] [0].content == thePlayer                // 3 in a diagonal
                && board[1] [1].content == thePlayer
                && board[2] [2].content == thePlayer
                || currentrow + currentcol == 2
                && board[0][2].content == thePlayer                 // 3 in the opposite diagonal
                && board[1][1].content == thePlayer
                && board[2][0].content == thePlayer);
    }
    public void paint()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {                      // Paints (displays) the full board
            for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                board[row][col].paint();
                if (col < COLUMNS - 1)
                    System.out.println("|");
            }
            System.out.println();
            if (row < ROWS - 1) {
                System.out.println("-----------");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the code to print out the display in the correct way. I think there must be a simple mistake I have made either in the paint() method or when I initialized the grid. Please can someone see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: You are using `println` which is a "print line". The next print will be on a distinct line. Use `print` if you don't want to jump on the next line. It seems the same in `Box.paint()`. Note that the box should not be printing in the `System.out` but returning a `String`. Let the `Grid` manage the printing.

Comment: Thank you so I changed all the println to print. Cant believe I did that!! But this is what is happening to the grid now:

Comment: Tic-Tac-Toe
------------

Player 'X', enter move (row [1-3] column [1-3]): 2
2
   
|   
|   
-----------   
| X 
|   
-----------   
|   
|   
Player 'O', enter move (row [1-3] column [1-3]):

Comment: See the answer. Note that your comment don't really show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your painting methods.

```
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {                      // Paints (displays) the full board
    for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
        board[row][col].paint();
        if (col < COLUMNS - 1)
            System.out.print("|");
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (row < ROWS - 1) {
        System.out.println("-----------");
    }
}
```

First, you need to use `println` only when needed, the rest of the time just use `print`.

And the same is for `Box.paint` not visible here. But it seems to be using `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print`.

Another thing, `Box.paint` should return a `String` instead of sending message in the console. The board is responsible of the painting, not the box.

```
public String paint(){
    return content; //return a `String` " ", "X" or "O"
}
```

---

Tested with :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    print(new String[][]{
            {"X", " ", "O"},
            {" ", " ", " "},
            {"O", " ", "X"}
        });
}

private static void print(String[][] board){
    int ROWS = board.length;
    int COLUMNS = board[0].length;
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {                      // Paints (displays) the full board
        for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
            System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            if (col < COLUMNS - 1)
                System.out.print("|");
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (row < ROWS - 1) {
            System.out.println("-----");
        }
    }
}
```

Giving :

```
X| |O
-----
 | | 
-----
O| |X
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to give you the answer with 100% certainty if you don't post all of the code. Can you add the implementation of `Box` and the `main` method?

The problem seems to be that you are doing `System.out.println("|");` when you should be doing `System.out.print("|");`. `System.out.println("|");` will also a new line causing the next thing printed to occur on the next line. You are already handling the newline for the end of the row correctly (the `System.out.println();` so `System.out.print("|");` should be all you need to do.

Working example with the fix: https://repl.it/repls/DimgreyOutlandishFlashdrive